# Mongoid "find" returns nil, when "find_by" retrieves record

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid to access a MongoDB database, however I'm running into an odd problem.  It seems like I can only query for records using `find_by`, as `find` will always return nil:

```
invoices = Invoice.find({})
p "invoices"
p invoices
puts ''

invoice = Invoice.find_by({ _id: <ObjectId> })
p "invoice"
p invoice
puts ''
```

The second query using `find_by` will return a single record.  According to [the documentation](http://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html), `find` should be returning every record that satisfies the query.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful not to confuse the *Moped* syntax with the *Mongoid* syntax. For Mongoid, the docs describe the **find** method:

> Find a document or multiple documents by their ids. Will raise an error by default if any of the ids do not match

If you really want every record, `Invoice.all` can do the trick. (Also be careful with your find_by method. The Mongoid syntax varies from mongo's a bit, so you don't have to have the curlies around your params.)

Comment: I don't necessarily want to find every record, I want to find every record that satisfies a MongoDB query.  Does `find` not support queries outside of finding by _id?

Comment: Actually after re-reading the docs, I misunderstood how it works (IE more acting like `findById`).  Thanks!

Comment: If your query is simple, you can break it up into attributes to pass to find by. For more complicated queries, you need to read up on the DSL and probably switch to calling **where** on your collection. [Querying](http://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries)